# no text in textfield

Tags: java, layout, calculator

please help me with this code 
the text is not appearing in textfield although it is through cmd prompt but not in textfield

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;



public class listener11
{
    private JFrame f;
    private JButton b;
    private JTextField tf;
    public static String str;


    public  listener11()
    {
        f=new JFrame("Listener1");
        b=new JButton("Press");
        b.setActionCommand("Button b1 pressed");
        tf=new JTextField(30);
    }

    public void launchframe()
    {
         f.setLayout(null);
         b.addActionListener(new Buttonlistener());
         b.setBounds(200,200,100,100);
         tf.setBounds(100,100,200,50);
         tf.setText(str);
         f.add(b);
         f.add(tf);
         f.setSize(400,400);

         f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]arg)
    {
         listener11 l1=new listener11();
         l1.launchframe();
    }
}

class Buttonlistener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        listener11.str="Action took place \n button's command is"+e.getActionCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really accept answers for your questions (click the check mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

When the `actionPerformed` method is invoked, you're just changing the value of the `str` variable. That doesn't automatically update the text box - just because you've called

```
tf.setText(str);
```

doesn't mean it will automatically look at the `str` variable the whole time. If you want to set the text again, call `tf.setText` again. (Alternatively, you can get into the whole model/view/controller business which is how Swing is meant to work, but that's considerably more complicated. For the moment you're probably best off sticking to the simple approach.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only setting the text to null (as str is null in the launchframe() method).  You need to call setText with a valid string even though you assign that string later, the text field still has null.